# Entity Framework Core 3 raw SQL missing methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to use EF Core 3 to delete all rows from a table like:

```
db.MyTable.ExecuteSqlRaw("delete from MyTable;");
```

But I get the error:

> DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlRaw' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The Microsoft breaking changes page for EF Core 3 does not offer any advice on if there are special packages required to enable this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fromsql-executesql-and-executesqlasync-have-been-renamed

These are the Nuget packages I have installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Queryable" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Note that `FromSqlRaw` is available, but `ExecuteSqlRaw`, `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` , etc are not.

**EDIT**: I added a `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and the error has changed to:

> 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlRaw' and the best extension method overload 'RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DatabaseFacade'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My edit about the new error led me to an answer:

The Microsoft Breaking Changes documentation is just not providing examples for the Execute methods.  To get that to work you have to go through the "Database" property instead.  So in short, to use those:

1. Make sure you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
2. If using an execute use `myContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"...sql to excxute...")`

Comment: how do you het a value back from Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw( though cant find the answer

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRaw` doesn't give you a response. Use `FromSqlRaw` if you want that (and change `myContext.Database` to `myContext.MyTable`).

Comment: I have the nuget and it still doesn't show me as available method

Comment: thx "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" did it for me, i am now able to use context.(some db set item).FromSqlRaw ;)

Answer (score 10):

I had similar issue with dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw() and it has been fixed by installing package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer without even using the package.

try `install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in your current project.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add NuGet package reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions` to your project.

Comment: In .NET 5 (net5.0) it's `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`. Function name is now "FromSqlRaw" (on DbSet).